# When I open an .xlsx file with LibreOffice Calc, it has no formatting

Tags: libreoffice

When I download an .xlsx file from the internet and open it with LibreOffice Calc, it is just not the same, it has no formatting, see the screenshots below:

[image: .xlsx file opened with LibreOffice Calc]

[image: .xlsx file opened with Microsoft Office Excel]

Would you please help me fix this?

Comment: Can you share the link to the file?

Comment: try this [app](http://wps-community.org/) for officelike experience

Comment: Here's the link to the file: http://rippedbody.com/diet-progress-tracking/
You just have to scroll down the page and you just click this: "You can download a copy of the progress tracker spreadsheet immediately for free, here."

Comment: You evidently have access to a newer verion of excel:  Open the file in Excel, and save it as an excel 2003 workbook.  Libre will open this older file with the formats intact.

Comment: @CharlesGreen, that worked, however the excel file was not opened on my laptop, I have only Linux. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: You could try the [online and free version of Office](https://login.microsoftonline.com/), and Google documents also opened the xlsx file.